# Getting "NOT NULL constraint failed" when writing non-null data with Java, JDBC, Sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a Java application which uses a SQLite database to capture "StatusEvent" objects. A StatusEvent looks like this:

```
public class StatusEvent
{
    private final String statusId;
    private final RefreshValue value;
    private final Instant createdAt;

    public StatusEvent(String id, RefreshValue currentValue)
    {

        Objects.requireNonNull(id, "StatusId must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(currentValue, "RefreshValue must not be null");

        statusId = id;
        value = currentValue;
        createdAt = Instant.now();
    }
     
     // Simple getters omitted
}
```

Where RefreshValue is an object that could contain different types of status values such as int, float, or String. The important thing is that StatusEvent is immutable, and that the 'statusId' is checked for null before construction.

Then I am using the following code below which receives StatusEvent objects and stores them in a LinkedBlockingQueue in order create batches. Every 200ms, the executor runs 'writebatch' which drains the queue, and tries to commit the data for all of the StatusEvents in the current batch.

The problem is that I can occasionally get an error when writing to the database: "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL]  A NOT NULL constraint failed (NOT NULL constraint failed: status.status_id)" I am failing to see how this is possible given the immutable StatusEvent class. Is there some way, given the way that the database is configured, that data is lost between leaving the application and hitting the database? Additionally, it seems that depending on the number of StatusEvent objects being received, the write speed to the database is not fast enough to keep up. After sustained stressful periods there may be several seconds between the creation of the StatusEvent (ie the timestamp in the constructor) and the 'created_at' time in the database. (StatusEvents are received by the StatusEventDB.accept() almost immediately after they are created). Looking for any help fixing either or both of these issues.

```
public class StatusEventDB
{
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS status";

    private static final String MAKE_TABLES =
                    "CREATE TABLE status (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "status_id TEXT NOT NULL, " + "value TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, " +
                        "created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f')))";

    private static final String SE_STRING =
                    "INSERT INTO status (status_id, value, time) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    private final Connection connection;
    private final PreparedStatement insertSEStatement;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    protected final LinkedBlockingQueue<StatusEvent> buffer =
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    StatusEventDB() throws SQLException
    {
        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
        config.setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.WAL);
        config.setCacheSize(32768);
        config.setTransactionMode(SQLiteConfig.TransactionMode.EXCLUSIVE);
        config.setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.NORMAL);
        config.setTempStore(TempStore.MEMORY);
        config.setBusyTimeout(5000);

        this.connection = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/mydir/test.db",
                                       config.toProperties());

        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement())
        {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement.executeUpdate(DROP_TABLE);
            statement.executeUpdate(MAKE_TABLES);
        }

        insertSEStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SE_STRING);

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::writeBatch, 200, 200,
                                          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void accept(StatusEvent se)
    {
        buffer.add(se);
    }

    private void writeBatch()
    {
        int bufferSize = buffer.size();

        if (0 < bufferSize)
        {
            List<StatusEvent> commitBatch = new ArrayList<>(bufferSize);

            buffer.drainTo(commitBatch, bufferSize);

            try
            {
                for (StatusEvent se : commitBatch)
                {
                    insertSEStatement.setString(1, se.getStatusId());
                    insertSEStatement.setString(2, se.getValue().getString());
                    insertSEStatement.setString(3, se.createdAt().toString());
                    insertSEStatement.addBatch();
                }
                insertSEStatement.executeBatch();
                connection.commit();

            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```